# What browsers support the HTML5 device orientation feature?

Tags: html, device-orientation

I tried looking at http://slides.html5rocks.com/#slide-orientation and it's not working in Chrome 10 (dev channel), which I thought supported that entire slideshow. I also tried loading the same slide with the Nexus One, which is the phone used for images in the [specification](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source-orientation.html), but that didn't work either. Does any device/browser currently support deviceorientation? Would it work on laptops that have the technology?

Also, what is that slide supposed to do when orientation is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None so far, but people in the WebKit community are implementing it. Hopefully in a couple of months it will be available. Usually timeframes for new features are not set in stone.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Chrome 11.0.696.0 on a Macbook Pro, and that device orientation link works exactly how I imagine it should.

it doesn't seem to work in either Safari 5.0.3
or Firefox 3.6

it also doesn't work on my iphone 3gs

Comment: I'll try Chrome 11 on Windows later today when I get home. I'll be happy to see support for this feature!

Comment: this seems to indicate it works in Firefox 3.6, however it doesnt work on mine.
http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1585-Mozilla-Releases-Firefox-3-6-Featuring-Better-HTML-5-Support-CSS-Gradients-and-Device-Orientation

p.s. my friend also reports that it works on Chrome 11 on a Thinkpad

Comment: I just tried Chrome 11 on a Thinkpad and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: oh. maybe it only works on some thinkpads.

you can kinda see what its supposed to do in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8wv_-RL6NU

Answer (score 1):

Does this help at all: http://www.quirksmode.org/m/table.html#t50

Comment: Erm, no, because it doesn't discuss (this sort of) orientation.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [technology preview](http://my.opera.com/core/blog/2011/03/23/webcam-orientation-preview) of Opera Mobile that supports device orientation and the  replacement, `getUserMedia()` API.